# Set UIImage color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I am on swift 4, and my goal is to change the color of a system `UIImage` in code. I declare the image with

```
    let defaultImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
```

But when I change its tint color with:

```
 let grayDefaultImage = defaultImage?.withTintColor(.gray)
```

The `grayDefaultImage` still display the standard blue color. Next I use an extension

```
//MARK: -UIImage extension
extension UIImage {

    /// @Todo: this blurs the image for some reason
    func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        color.setFill()

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)

        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        context?.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
        context?.fill(rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

And the image renders in a very "pixelated" or "low res" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[withTintColor(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3327300-withtintcolor) say: `The new image uses the same rendering mode as the original image.`

So if original image's rendering mode is `.alwaysTemplate`, means image will ignoring its color information. you need set mode to `.alwaysOriginal`:

```swift
defaultImage?.withTintColor(.gray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: When I do this:     `let defaultImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
    defaultImage?.withTintColor(.gray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    friendView.image = defaultImage`. The image still shows up in the default blue.

Comment: @chibro2 `withTintColor` not change `defaultImage`, you need use `withTintColor` return value.